# Javascript message passing to populate table

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hello I have the following code, I am attempting to pass two messages from the confirm.js to the background.js script. The message contains the current url and if the user has chosen to continue from a confirmation dialog. I am trying to create a new row in the window.html table and populate it with each column with the url and the clicked status.

The information used to populate the table is seen in the console.log in  background.js as request.continued and request.url.

**Confirm.js**

```
if (confirm("User continued")) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'continued', url: window.location.href, continued: "yes"});
} else {
    alert ("You pressed Cancel!");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'cancelled', url: window.location.href, continued: "no"});
}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
if (request.type === 'continued') {
    console.log(request.continued, request.url);
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.extension.getURL('dialog.html'),            
        active: false
            });
}
//NON WORKING ATTEMPT INCLUDED FOR CLARITY PURPOSES

w = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()

var table = w.document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = request.continued;
cell2.innerHTML = request.url;
});
```

**Window.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td nowrap>URL:</td>
                <td align="right"><span id="total">CLICKED</span></td> **ROWS & COLUMNS UNDER HERE**
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main problem area surrounds dynamically generating the table rows and using identifying the HTML elements.

Comment: Is window.html declared as browser_action default popup? If so, it's a separate page with its own URL and it's not related to the *background page* which is also a separate page with its own URL. So background.js should be only in manifest.json where it declares a *background page*. As for window.html you need a separate script file just for that window - note, the popup exists only while shown, and it has its own devtools accessible by right-clicking the popup, then clicking "inspect". See also the [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: it is not declared as the default popup currently. I am unsure how to identify the html elements in window.html and manipulate them through the background script i am aware they currently do not have any ids.

Comment: window.html is still a separate page so the above comment still applies.

Comment: I have included the full background code to show how i am attempting to access the html file

Comment: The second chrome.windows.create has a different meaning for `type: 'popup'` as you can see in the documentation it's just a type of window that doesn't have an address bar. In your case it doesn't do anything because you didn't specify `url`.

Comment: I have removed the tab creation element and have included my attempt at a solution to perhaps give better understanding of what i  am trying to do